# Is there a way I can pass another parameter to use inside this window callback function?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, functional-programming

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

So, this is the function prototype for a Window Procedure of some window created using the Windows API (win32). It is used to process some window messages like when the user clicks the Close button, or resize the window.

```
WNDCLASSA window_class = {0};
window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
window_class.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
window_class.hInstance = instance;
```

This is where this function is used, as a WNDPROC type for a window class WNDCLASSA, as defined in the win32 API. As you can see, I didn't pass any of those four parameters defined in the function prototype.

I need to pass some extra parameters to be processed in some messege inside the WindowProc function, but I don't know how to pass them, and I don't want to use global variables for this. I read that that is a way to do this using the WM_CREATE message, but I'm not sure if this method is exactly what I want to do.

Is there anyone with experience in using the win32 API that can guide me through this?

Comment: That function is called by the windows operating system, not by you. You may not change its signature. You may however declare variables as static inside the function if you want them to retain their values.

Comment: Which specific message do you have in mind? Are you sending it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have a render buffer struct to draw the window. I'd like to change some values of this struct when the window receives a WM_SIZE message. What I have now is a global variable of this struct, which get updated every time a WM_SIZE message is received. I'd like to not have this as a global and just pass this struct as a parameter in Callback function.

Comment: You don't send WM_SIZE, the system does. It's not going to send you your information.

Answer (score 3):

When creating the window, you can associate a user-defined value to it, such as an object pointer. There are several ways you can do that association:

- `SetWindowLongPtr(GWLP_USERDATA)`
- `SetProp()`
- `SetWindowSubclass()`

In your particular situation, `SetWindowSubclass()` would be particularly useful, as it allows you to pass a user-defined value directly to your message procedure as an extra parameter, rather than storing the value inside the HWND. The downside to this approach is that your subclass procedure won't see any of the initial setup messages that `CreateWindow/Ex()` sends, and you can't access the value from the HWND itself.

For the other `Set` functions, you can setup the association manually. You could wait until `CreateWindow/Ex()` exits before calling one of the functions, but it is generally better to pass your user-defined value to the `lParam` parameter of `CreateWindow/Ex()`, then you can receive the value inside your message procedure in the `WM_NCCREATE` message and assign it to the HWND using the desired `Set` function, and then you can retrieve the value from the HWND at any time, especially on subsequent messages inside your message procedure, using the corresponding `Get` function.

Comment: The OP is *registering* a window class. That allows them to associate an arbitrary amount of memory for their use by passing a non-zero [cbWndExtra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassexw) value.

Comment: @IInspectable true, but since the window class already has `sizeof(void*)` number of extra bytes allotted for free for `GWL_USERDATA`, using `cbWndExtra` is usually unnecessary unless you need to reserve more bytes than that, which most people don't

Comment: `GWLP_USERDATA` isn't meant to be used by the implementer of a window class. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlongptrw) recommends this: *"This data is intended for use by the application that created the window."*

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a custom message the usual answer is to make a struct and pass a pointer to an instance of that struct as one of the message parameters. Plenty of existing messages follow this model (pretty much all WM_NOTIFY messages that require more than just an NMHDR).

If you want a value available to *all* messages handled by a particular window class an easy way is to set the GWLP_USERDATA value with SetWindowLongPtr then retrieve it with GetWindowLongPtr, that does have the drawback of not being extensible through sub-classing. If that is a concern I would follow the MFC model and use a CBT hook to associate an instance of a custom data type with the HWND.